# Implementing std::vector::push_back strong exception safety

Tags: c++, containers, c++20, exception-safety

I'm implementing my own vector based on post-2018 San Diego draft ([N4791](https://wg21.link/n4791)) and have some questions regarding implementing strong exception safety.

Here is some code:

```
template <typename T, typename Allocator>
void Vector<T, Allocator>::push_back(const T& value)
{
    if (buffer_capacity == 0)
    {
        this->Allocate(this->GetSufficientCapacity(1));
    }
    if (buffer_size < buffer_capacity)
    {
        this->Construct(value);
        return;
    }
    auto new_buffer = CreateNewBuffer(this->GetSufficientCapacity(
        buffer_size + 1), allocator);
    this->MoveAll(new_buffer);
    try
    {
        new_buffer.Construct(value);
    }
    catch (...)
    {
        this->Rollback(new_buffer, std::end(new_buffer));
        throw;
    }
    this->Commit(std::move(new_buffer));
}

template <typename T, typename Allocator>
void Vector<T, Allocator>::Allocate(size_type new_capacity)
{
    elements = std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::allocate(allocator,
        new_capacity);
    buffer_capacity = new_capacity;
}

template <typename T, typename Allocator> template <typename... Args>
void Vector<T, Allocator>::Construct(Args&&... args)
{
    // TODO: std::to_address
    std::allocator_traits<Allocator>::construct(allocator,
        elements + buffer_size, std::forward<Args>(args)...);
    ++buffer_size;
}

template <typename T, typename Allocator>
Vector<T, Allocator> Vector<T, Allocator>::CreateNewBuffer(
    size_type new_capacity, const Allocator& new_allocator)
{
    Vector new_buffer{new_allocator};
    new_buffer.Allocate(new_capacity);
    return new_buffer;
}

template <typename T, typename Allocator>
void Vector<T, Allocator>::Move(iterator first, iterator last, Vector& buffer)
{
    if (std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<T> ||
        !std::is_copy_constructible_v<T>)
    {
        std::move(first, last, std::back_inserter(buffer));
    }
    else
    {
        std::copy(first, last, std::back_inserter(buffer));
    }
}

template <typename T, typename Allocator
void Vector<T, Allocator>::MoveAll(Vector& buffer)
{
    Move(std::begin(*this), std::end(*this), buffer);
}

template <typename T, typename Allocator>
void Vector<T, Allocator>::Rollback(Vector& other, iterator last) noexcept
{
    if (!std::is_nothrow_move_constructible_v<T> &&
        std::is_copy_constructible_v<T>)
    {
        return;
    }
    std::move(std::begin(other), last, std::begin(*this));
}

template <typename T, typename Allocator>
void Vector<T, Allocator>::Commit(Vector&& other) noexcept
{
    this->Deallocate();
    elements = other.elements;
    buffer_capacity = other.buffer_capacity;
    buffer_size = other.buffer_size;
    allocator = other.allocator;
    other.elements = nullptr;
    other.buffer_capacity = 0;
    other.buffer_size = 0;
}
```

I see 2 problems with this code. I've tried to follow the `std::move_if_noexcept` logic, but what if the element is nothrow move constructible but `allocator_traits::construct` throws exception in, say, some logging code inside custom allocator? Then my `MoveAll` call will throw and produce only basic guarantee. Is this a defect in the standard? Should there be more strict wording on `Allocator::construct`?

And another one in `Rollback`. It really produces strong guarantee only if the moved elements are nothrow move assignable. Otherwise, again, only basic guarantee. Is this how it is supposed to be?

Comment: The paper says: Note: this is an early draft. It’s known to be incomplet and incorrekt, and it has lots of bad formatting

Comment: So maybe we should fix it before C++20 ships?

Comment: Yes, the more people the review the docs the better. This forum is a good place to highlight these issues.

Comment: @Damian Yes, that is the working _draft_ of the C++ standard.

Comment: First construct the value, then move the elements!

Comment: @Oliv: You're not allowed to. The object isn't required to be DefaultConstructible, nor is it required to be MoveAssignable.

Comment: @NicolBolas End what is the issue? This is how it has always been implemented: 1) allocate a buffer, 2) construct the value in the **new buffer** at vector.size() 3) move  the values from the old buffer to the new one.

Comment: @Oliv: Maybe I don't understand what you mean by "construct the value". If that means doing something which invokes a constructor for the type `T`, then no, that's not allowed. Allocator aware containers are not allowed to directly construct the types; they are only allowed to construct them *through* the allocator, via `allocator_traits<Allocator>::construct(a, ptr, ...)`.

Comment: @NicolBolas Oh, I missed that one. Also to move the object allocator::construct is called! I just focussed on a weirdness of the code that implicated an unnecessary rool_back

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The range-based `std::move/copy` functions are not capable of providing a strong exception guarantee. In the event of an exception, you need an iterator to the last element that was successfully copied/moved, so that you can undo things properly. You have to do the copy/move manually (or write a specialized function to do so).

As for the particulars of your question, the standard does not really address what should happen if `construct` emits an exception which is not thrown from within the constructor of the object being construction. The intent of the standard (for reasons I will explain below) is probably that this circumstance should never happen. But I have yet to find any statement in the standard about this. So let's assume for a moment that this is intended to be possible.

In order for allocator-aware containers to be able to offer the strong-exception guarantee, `construct` at the very least must not throw *after* constructing the object. After all, you don't know what exception was thrown, so otherwise you would not be able to tell if the object was successfully constructed or not. That would make implementing the standard required behavior impossible. So let us assume that the user has not done something that makes implementation impossible.

Given this circumstance, you can write your code assuming that any exception emitted by `construct` means that the object was not constructed. If `construct` emits an exception despite being given arguments that would invoke a `noexcept` constructor, then you assume that the constructor was never called. And you write your code accordingly.

In the case of copying, you only need to delete any already-copied elements (in reverse order of course). The move case is a bit trickier, but still quite doable. You have to move-assign each successfully-moved object back into its original position.

The problem? `vector<T>::*_back` does not require that `T` be MoveAssignable. It only requires that `T` be Move**Insertable**: that is, you can use an allocator to construct them in uninitialized memory. But you're not moving it into uninitialized memory; you need to move it to where a moved-from `T` already exists. So to preserve this requirement, you would need to destroy all of the `T`s that were successfully moved-from and then MoveInsert them back into place.

But since MoveInsertion requires using `construct`, which as previously established might throw... ***oops***. Indeed, this very thing is preciesely *why* `vector`'s reallocation functions do not move *unless* the type is nothrow-moveable or is non-copyable (and if it's the latter case, you *don't* get the strong-exception guarantee).

So it seems pretty clear to me that any allocator's `construct` method is expected by the standard to only throw if the selected constructor throws. There's no other way to implement the required behavior in `vector`. But given that there is no *explicit* statement of this requirement, I would say that this is a defect in the standard. And it's not a new defect, since I looked through the C++17 standard rather than the working paper.

Apparently this has been the subject of an [LWG issue since 2014](https://wg21.link/lwg2461), with solutions to it being... troublesome.

Comment: I use `std::back_inserter` which calls `push_back` which calls `Construct` which calls `allocator_traits::construct`. Allocator is being copied inside `CreateNewBuffer` so everything is allocator-aware.

Comment: @Lyberta: Fixed

Comment: Scoped allocators break that expectation rather systematically. This is LWG 2461.

Comment: @T.C.: All this really shows just how broken our allocator model is. Allocators have no business being the means by which we *construct* objects; they should have always been about allocating the storage for them.

Comment: Ironically, nobody seems to be caring about fancy allocator stuff. Take a look at [this libstdc++ bug](https://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=57272) reported 5 years ago that is still not fixed, which essentially forbids any fancy `pointer` allocator. Not to mention how ugly that `rebind` syntax is.